# Retorfit query param taking & and ? together

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have to execute the following API call

URL `https://devipapi.octavehi.com/api/state/select-list-items?countryId=236`

The retrofit function I create is

```
@GET("country/state/select-list-items?")
suspend fun fetchStates(@Query("countryId") id: Int): Response<List<ServerState>>
```

But I get this URL returned from retrofit

```
https://devipapi.octavehi.com/api/country/state/select-list-items?&countryId=236
```

ampercent (&) get appended along with ?

How to fix this?

Comment: Remove `?`. It assumes an URL without _query string_ which is a parameter list in the form `?...=...&...=...&...=...`. As the URL already contains a question mark, it takes an ampersand before the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by

```
@GET("city/select-list-items")
suspend fun fetchCities(@Query(value="stateId", encoded = true) id: Int): Response<List<ServerCity>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove '?' from the @GET

```
@GET("country/state/select-list-items")
suspend fun fetchStates(@Query("countryId") id: Int): Response<List<ServerState>>
```